# Advantage is given after a reckless slide tackle and the affected team scores. Yellow still to be given?

Tags: rules, football

Orange team commits a yellow card slide tackle on blue, but play is allowed on through advantage. The blue team scores.

Should the orange player still receive a yellow card for the challenge?

Comment: Reckless tackle? Then yes. Or what situation is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the outcome of the advantage is. If the offence needs caution/warning/card/sent off right away, it still deserves it afterwards and has to be sanctioned at the first stop, before play resumes.

From the [FIFA Laws of the Game](https://digitalhub.fifa.com/m/50518593a0941079/original/khhloe2xoigyna8juxw3-pdf.pdf):

> **Advantage**
>
> If the referee plays the advantage for an offence for which a caution / send off would have been issued had play been stopped, this **caution / send off must be issued when the ball is next out of play**, except for the denial of an obvious goal-scoring opportunity when the player is cautioned for unsporting
> behaviour.
>
> Advantage should not be applied in situations involving serious foul play,
> violent conduct or a second cautionable offence unless there is a clear
> opportunity to score a goal. The referee must send off the player when the ball
> 105 is next out of play but if the player plays the ball or challenges/interferes with an opponent, the referee will stop play, send off the player and restart with an indirect free kick, unless the player committed a more serious offence.